# Create a link inside vue bootstrap b-table cell

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I have a `b-table` compo

```
<b-table responsive 
         hover 
         :items="myItems" 
         :fields="myField">
```

On my items, I return a url from the back-end, so I want to do on my template

```
<template slot="my-link" slot-scope="data">
    <a href="data.item.link">link</a>
 </template>
```

The above doesn't work, it renders

```
<a href="data.item.link">link</a>
```

Instead of

```
<a href="https://mylink.com">link</a>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should bind it using `v-bind:href="..."` or shortly `:href="..."` with `b-link` component  :

```
 <template slot="my-link" slot-scope="data">
    <b-link :href="data.item.link">link</b-link>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want your data to be interpreted as a **javascript** object you need to specify it by using `v-bind:` or `:`. Other way its only a string.

So in your case you should do something like.

```
<a :href="data.item.link">link</a>
```